# JavaScript Namespace JavaDoc support in Eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, javadoc

I'm originally an electrical engineering guy, so my computer science terminology might be off, but I believe I do what is considered a "namespace":

```
var MyNamespace = (function(local1, local2, local3){
  // local1 === global1 and so on

  // private vars
  var foo;
  var bar;

  // private functions
  function isFooBar() {
    return foo == bar;
  }

  return {

    // public vars
    publicFoo: 'foo',
    publicBar: 'bar',

    // public functions
    foo: function() {
      return foo;
    },

    bar: function() {
      return bar;
    }

  };

})(global1, global2, global3);
```

It might not be the "best" practice, but it's what I and others on my team have been doing for ages.

Now the question: how do I get Eclipse to recognize the hierarchy?  I'd like to eventually get some kind of structure in the outline view like:

```
MyNamespace
  - local1 (private => global1)
  - local2 (private => global2)
  - local3 (private => global3)
  - foo (private)
  - bar (private)
  O foo() (private)
  O bar() (private)
  O foo() (public)
  O bar() (public)
```

if that makes sense (- for variable, O for function)

At the moment I can put the following JavaDoc comment before a variable or function:

```
/**
 * description
 * @memberOf MyModule
 */
```

And the function/variable will show up, but I still get some residual nodes for the MyNamespace variable as well as the unnamed function and the global -> local variables.

Without going into semantics of whether or not this is a "correct" way to program JavaScript namespaces, can anyone tell me perhaps a good way to get it so that my namespaces and their public/private vars/functions will show up properly in the outline tab?

Comment: What Eclipse extension are you using for JavaScript support?

Comment: I haven't explicitly installed one, however JBoss is installed, which seems to have quite a bit of tools.  I just figured Eclipse would have some good basic code hierarchy tools.  For smaller projects I use Notepad++ and they have great code hinting, completion and folding for several languages built in (off-topic, I know).  Here's all my installed extensions: http://tinypic.com/r/oswq4w/8